# How can i make batch.size dynamic in kafka producers?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

keeping batch.size small brings overhead of sending messages more frequently on producer and reduces throughput simultaneously and keeping it large causes wastage of memory.Is there any solution that this size can be dynamic according to the load?

Comment: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-1026

Comment: How do you predict the incoming load ? The incoming load of past 1 min may not be same as the next / future minute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only if you stop the previous producer and start a new one. A producer object needs all properties before sending any message. You cannot modify its properties in middle of the job.

Comment: So, what is best practice for setting up this property?

Comment: There are 2 perspectives of looking towards this problem: Latency and Throughput. You can have any one at a time not both. You can use linger.ms if you want to achieve maximum throughput and if you want maximum latency set linger.ms=0.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `linger.ms` combined with `batch.size` property. If you have set the `batch.size` as 5242880 (5 MB) and the `linger.ms` set to `10` ms. Then, the producer will wait until the batch size get filled / the linger time is reached.

See more about the [linger.ms](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#producerconfigs) property in the official documentation.